# How can I write character < in android strings.xml

Tags: android, xml

I want to write "<" in strings.xml file:

```
<string name="back">< Back</string>
```

I am getting an error.

How can I write character < in the strings.xml?

Comment: Use `&lt;`, I think.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `&#60` instead!

Check out [this page](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/specialcharacters.php) as well.

Hope this helps!